# Use Excel to sort and filter data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of IDs in column A and a corresponding performance related percentage, per week, in column B.  For a month time period, I need a list generated from column A where column B is consistently less than 68%.

Comment: How are you going to examine a month of data (which I'm assuming is set to 4 weeks for simplicity) if you only have one week's worth of data? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, also which version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert your data into a `Table, Insert>Tables>Table`
2. Sort your Table by Date
3. Filter your Table by the Date period(s) you're interested in.
4. Filter your Table by the Percentage value (<68%).
5. The remaining rows should have the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to go out on a limb and guess that your data look something like this:

[image: Performance data for Fred and Joe]

and that you’re interested in the fact that Fred was below 68 every week in May, and Joe was below 68 every week in June.  (Fred was below 68 four times in June, but, since I chose to base my weeks on Saturdays, June is a five-week month.)  Here’s an approach: create a list of unique names.  It might be best to do this on another sheet, but it’s probably good enough to move over a few columns.  [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/479530/150988) shows a technique for doing that (see the third through fifth paragraphs, starting with the word “Advanced”).  I’ll assume you put the list of unique names in Column `H`, starting in Row `2`.  Now, in cell `I2`, enter the following formula:

> `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$27, "="&H2, $B$2:$B$27, "<68", $C$2:$C$27, ">="&T$1, $C$2:$C$27, "<"&(EOMONTH(T$1,0)+1))=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$27, "="&H2, $C$2:$C$27, ">="&T$1, $C$2:$C$27, "<"&(EOMONTH(T$1,0)+1))`

and drag/fill it down through the last name.  Finally, enter the date of the first of the month into cell `T1`, and Column `I` will identify the personnel whose performance has been consistently bad:

[image: Results for May]
                            [image: Results for June]

Explanation: the second part of the formula,

```
COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$27, "="&H2, $C$2:$C$27, ">="&T$1, $C$2:$C$27, "<"&(EOMONTH(T$1,0)+1))
```

counts the rows for which the name (in Column `A`) matches the name in Column `H`, and the date (in Column `C`) is in the month indicated by cell `T1` –– on or after the first of the month but before (less than) the first day of the following month (i.e., the last day (“end of”) this month, plus one).  The first part,

```
COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$27, "="&H2, $B$2:$B$27, "<68", $C$2:$C$27, ">="&T$1, $C$2:$C$27, "<"&(EOMONTH(T$1,0)+1))
```

is the same thing, but with the `<68` restriction added.  So the overall formula checks whether the number of weeks this person was under 68 this month equals the number of weeks this person was present this month –– i.e., whether the person was under 68 every week.