# Sorting Common Values by Row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have two sets of data from two years as below which needed to be sorted by product and row. Eg. I need A2 and its product sales on the same row for both years.I have had a look at the the solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/479472/grouping-data-columns-by-shared-values) but don’t know how to adjust it.

```
    2012                 2011   
Product   Sales     Product  Sales
A1          5       A1         3
A2          7       A4         5
A3          2       A6         3
A4          5       A7         2
A5          3       A9         4
A6          4       A10        5
A7          3           
A8          4           
A9          5           
A10         6
```

This is the desired result which has the same product on each row for both years.

```
    2012                 2011   
Product   Sales     Product  Sales
A1          5       A1         3
A2          7           
A3          2           
A4          5       A4         5
A5          3       
A6          4       A6         3
A7          3       A7         2
A8          4           
A9          5       A9         4
A10         6       A10        5
```

My actual database has over 800 rows over 8 years so performing this task manually is too time consuming. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: `vlookup` will do exactly this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) function.

The syntax for vlookup is `VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)` where

- lookup_value is what you're trying to match, it can be a variable or a constant
- table_array is the table you are searching
- col_index_num is the column (starting with 1) of the table in which you are searching for the lookup_value
- range_lookup is whether you want it to return **exact matches only**; *true* or *false*

[image: VLOOKUP result]

Fill H2 with the formula `=VLOOKUP(G2;A:B;2;0)` and copy until H11.

Fill I2 with the formula `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2;C:D;2;0);0)` and copy until I11.

`IFERROR` is necessary because when the formula is looking for tha value `A2` for example it will not find it, so, we replace the error with `0`.

I think it is self explainable and make you able to figure out how to do this for the others columns.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits.. I believe my post is cohesive now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. However, when I enter the formula into the cell I get an error. This is an [image](http://imgur.com/E9VlV9l) of the error.

Comment: Well, there's a configuration in Excel that determines the delimiter for more than one parameter in the formula, in my case is the semicolon (;), maybe for you is the comma (,). Switch the `;` by `,` and let me know if it works for you.