# Excel prefixes or suffixes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column in Excel that contains a comma delimited list:

```
Header
1, 61
61
1, 61, 161
5, 55
```

I would like to extract this data so that I can count the occurrences of each item so that I would have the following results:

```
Count of Items
1    |    2
5    |    1
55   |    1
61   |    3
161  |    1
```

I tried countif with "*" but its a mess because in this case I have  prefixes or suffixes (1,61,161)

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**

**I would like to suggest UDF (User Defined Function) which not only counts occurrence of comma separated numbers but counts text also.**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Press **Alt+F11** to get VB editor then **Copy** & **Paste** this code as **Module.**

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Function CountOccurrence(SearchRange As Range, Phrase As String) As Long

  Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
  Dim sPat As String
  Dim V As Variant
  Dim I As Long, J As Long

  V = SearchRange

  Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  With RE
  .Global = True
  .MultiLine = True
  .ignorecase = True
  .Pattern = "(?:^|,\s*)" & Phrase & "(?:\s*,|$)"
  End With

  For I = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
  If RE.test(V(I, 1)) Then J = J + 1
  Next I

  CountOccurrence = J

  End Function
  ```
- Enter Criteria in Range `H18:H26`, then enter this Formula in Cell `I18` & fill it down.

`=CountOccurrence($G$18:$G$24,H18)`

**Option 2:**

*Enter this Formula in Cell `I18` & fill it down.*

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(H18,$G$18:$G$24)))
```

*Adjust cell references as needed.*

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(H18,$G$18:$G$24))) with this formula is confuses the 5 with 55 the same problem

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to split your numbers into separate cells:

   - select your data
   - on data tab select "split to columns"
   - select "delimited", next
   - select data is separated by "comma", finish
2. now you can use COUNTIF, e.g.
   `=COUNTIF($A$2:$C$5,E2)`

[image]

Comment: How do you get the list in column E?  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234: typed it:), as I understand it was not part of the question to generate unique list of items.

Comment: Many thanks for your promote answer, is there any other way without splitting them?

Comment: @MuhannadHaddad, 1. is your issue with splitting the data into separate columns only that you lose the original data? If so, that doesn't need to be an issue. You can either work from a copy of the data or tell it to split in another output location. This is a practical solution; any other approach gets very complicated.  2. Do you have a method of generating the list of unique values to use with this solution? If the source data is substantial and it would be a job to reliably create that list, there's another approach to create the list and counts at the same time, but it's some extra steps.

Comment: No splitting the data isnt a problem, the thing is with splitting i have to redo the split each time i change something in the original table

Comment: i like your solution of splitting the data but is there a way to refresh itself automatically once the data changes the split changes too?

Comment: In my answer [here](https://superuser.com/q/479472/150988#479530 "Grouping data columns by shared values") I show a way to generate the list of unique values (i.e., Column E, above), but, unfortunately, it is still manual intensive (i.e., only partially automated).   Cc: @fixer1234

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have a solution, but I'll toss in a non-VBA solution that handles dynamic data.  It uses some helper columns that you can prepopulate to an arbitrarily large range.  When there is no associated data, the cells will be blank.  Some of helper columns could be eliminated; they're included to minimize repetition, but all of the helper columns can be hidden.

[image]

Your data is in column A.  Column B determines the number of values in each entry based on the number of commas.  The formula in B3 is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",""))+1)
```

Column C is just the cumulative component count from column B.  C2 is entered as `0`.  The formula in C3 is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",SUM(B3:B$3))
```

Populate columns B and C to as many rows as you might ever have data for.  You can always extend those columns if needed.

Column E is just for convenience.  It provides an index for the parsed values.  You could hard-code the `1` and then add 1 to it for each successive row.  For no good reason, I based it on the row number (the `-2` in the formula below is to adjust the values to start at `1`).  Cells beyond the total number of values get a blank.  My formula in E3:

```
=IF(ROW()-2>MAX($C$2:$C$10),"",ROW()-2)
```

Column F is just to avoid formula repetition.  It pulls the relevant Column A entry from which the current component will be parsed.  The formula in F3 is:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET($A$2,MATCH(E3-1,$C$2:$C$10,1),0),"")
```

It finds the appropriate entry by comparing the component number in column E with the cumulative component count in column C.

Column G is the parsed component values, all in a single contiguous column that is easy to work with.  The formula in G3 is:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(F3,",",REPT(" ",LEN(F3))),(E3-INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH(E3-1,$C$2:$C$10,1))-1)*LEN(F3)+1,LEN(F3))),"")
```

This determines which element to parse from the column F entry by subtracting the cumulative element count of the last "completed" input record from the current element number.

Columns E through G should be propagated to enough rows to cover the anticipated number of component values (at least several times the number of data rows).  Note that all the formulas above that refer to the range $C$2:$C$10 should be adjusted to include the full range of your data.

Now that you have all of the parsed elements in a nice column, there are a variety of ways to aggregate them and get the counts.  I used a pivot table, which also gives you the list of unique values at the same time.

Select the full pre-populated range of column G for the pivot table.  Use that field for the rows window and the values window (select count as the aggregation).  The range will include blanks in the unused rows, so use the built-in filter to deselect blanks.

When the data changes, just refresh the pivot table and verify that any new element values are selected in the filter.