# How to create a new option box in Excel filter and apply a single filter for multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel worksheet. In column A, there is a list of objects (around 50 of them); in other columns listed are features of these objects. Columns E, F, G are of particular importance to me. They contain numerical values such as `1`, `7`, etc., numerical-letter values like `16B`,`17C`, and there also are comma-separated values that contain at least a couple of numerical and/or numerical-letter values, e.g. `24, 13B, 15G` or `17A, 20B, 16`. There also are some empty cells in these columns. Here is a print screen of the [worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGsmx.png).

I would like to use filters on columns E, F, G.

This is how I would like the filters to [be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC56G.png).

And this is how they currently [are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk7G6.png).

For instance, I would like to filter column F by a numerical-letter value such as ‘17C’. Ideally, what remains would be cells that contain ‘17C’, e.g. `17C`, `17C, 24A`, `16B, 17B, 17C, 24A, 24F`, etc.

Also, I would like to filter column F by a numerical value like ‘6’. Ideally, what remains would be cells that contain ‘6’, e.g. `1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 13, 15, 20`, `6`, but not `6E, 7C, 13C`, nor `6A`, nor `16B, 17A, 19C`.

I would like to be able to filter on all possible values used in the columns, i.e. on `1`, `1B`, `2`, `2D`, `2E`, … , `20`, `24A`, `24F`, etc.

I would like to apply such filtering on columns E, F, and G.

It would be wonderful if I could do without helper columns. But shall that be impossible to do without them, then I would happily use them.

I hope I managed to express my struggle clearly.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are https://superuser.com/users/1056981/ken-lee and https://superuser.com/users/1057003/ken-lee.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your question.  … … … … … … … … P.S. Please register your merged account.

Comment: (1) I found your post to be very hard to understand.  Please review my edit; if it’s wrong, fix it. (2) What do you want to happen with a cell that contains exactly (only) `13`, or `13B`?  How about `137` or `213` (with or without another number)?  How about `13, 42` or `7, 13, 19`? (You show only examples where `13` is the *last* number.) (3) And it might help if you explained exactly what you mean by “filter”.  I guess you mean “non-destructively hide all matching rows (in their entirety), allowing quick and easy unhiding”, but I don’t know for sure.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Are willing to use “helper columns”? … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Building on point #3 — You posted an image of the existing filter dialog, which doesn’t suit your purposes, and how you want it to be modified.  Rather than that, it would be more useful if you showed us a *representative* sample sheet (include values like `13`, `13B`, `137`, `213`, ``13, 42`` and ``7, 13, 19`` if you have them) and what you want to be able to do with them. (5) Is the number `13` of particular, enduring importance to you?  Or will you want to filter on `17` next week, and `43` next month?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Scott. I edited my original post to make my problem clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Select all three columns, then select the filter button in the ribbon. You can unselect all, then select 13 in each column.

Now that I read your updated details, try selecting all three columns, Conditional formatting, Highlight cell rules, Text that contains "13".

Answer (score 0):

I’ve never heard of any such capability native to Excel. 
However, I have constructed a solution that — I believe —
gives the results you want.

Assuming that the column layout that you show in your question is accurate:

- In cell `I2`, enter the formula `=OR(AND(E2=$H$1,E2<>""), LEFT(E2, LEN($H$1)+1)=($H$1&","), RIGHT(E2, LEN($H$1)+1)=(" "&$H$1), NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(" "&$H$1&",", E2))))
  =OR(AND(E2=$H$1,E2<>""), LEFT(E2, LEN($H$1)+1)=($H$1&","), RIGHT(E2, LEN($H$1)+1)=(" "&$H$1), NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(" "&$H$1&",", E2))))`

  This will be a helper column. 
  I’ll discuss this formula in some detail a little later. 
  For now, notice that it references `E2` multiple times.
  This is testing the value in `E2`; i.e., Column `E`.
- Drag/fill cell `I2` to the right, to cell `K2`. 
  Now the formula in `J2` is testing Column `F`
  and `K2` is testing Column `G`.

  Helper columns can be put wherever you want. 
  You can put the above formulas in Columns `X`, `Y` and `Z` if you want —
  or `AE`, `AF` and `AG`.
- In cell `H2`, enter `=OR(I2:K2)`. 
  Obviously, if you relocated the `I`-`J`-`K` helper columns,
  adjust this to match.
- Select the helper column cells
  (`H2` through `K2`, or wherever you have put them)
  and drag/fill down to cover all the rows that have data.
- Filter Column `H`.

Now,

- Enter an alphanumeric value, like `1B`, `17A` or `24`, in cell `H1`.
- Activate the filter on Column `H` to show only **TRUE** values. 
  You will now see only the rows where Column `F`, `G` or `H`
  contains the value you have entered in `H1`.

Unfiltered:

[image]

Filtered:

[image]

OK; the formula in the helper columns
(described above as `I`, `J` and `K`) looks like

```
=OR(expression1, expression2, expression3, expression4)
```

where the four expressions are:

- `AND(E2=$H$1,E2<>"")`. 
  This tests whether the value in Column `E`
  is simply equal to the value in `H1` (but not blank). 
  For example, this will be TRUE for `E3` if the value in `H2` is `24`.
- `LEFT(E2, LEN($H$1)+1)=($H$1&",")`. 
  This tests whether the value in Column `E` begins with the value in `H1`. 
  More precisely, whether the value in Column `E`
  begins with the value in `H1` followed by a comma. 
  So, for example, for `F3` this will be TRUE for `16B`
  but FALSE for `1` or `16`.
- `RIGHT(E2, LEN($H$1)+1)=(" "&$H$1)`. 
  Mirror image of the above;
  this tests whether the value in Column `E` ends with the value in `H1`. 
  More precisely, whether the value in Column `E` ends with the value in `H1`
  preceded by a space. 
  So, for example, for `F3` this will be TRUE for `19C`
  but FALSE for `9C` or `C`.

  Note that the above three tests are case-insensitive, because `string1 = string2`
  is case-insensitive in Excel.
- `NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(" "&$H$1&",", E2)))`. 
  This tests whether the value in Column `E` contains the value in `H1`. 
  More precisely, whether the value in Column `E` contains the value in `H1`
  preceded by a space and followed by a comma. 
  This is case-insensitive, because the `SEARCH` function is case-insensitive.

So the formula in `I2` tests
whether the value in `E2` contains the value in `H1` in some way.

So the formula in `H2` tests
whether any value in row 2 (Columns `E`, `F` or `G`)
contains the value in `H1`.

---

If you want to generate a list of the alphanumeric values
in Columns `E`, `F` and `G`
(e.g., `1B`, `2D`, `2E`, `5C`, `24`, `16B`, `17A`, `19C`, etc.),
that can be done, but I won’t do that now.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Scott. This gives the result I want but this filtering is not the most intuitive. I assume that's a problem of Excel. Could you explain to me what you mean by your last paragraph? Also, do you think such filtering could be done without helper columns?

Comment: See the oddly titled [Excel prefixes or suffixes](https://superuser.com/q/1453927/150988), which discusses a problem with data *very* similar to yours — i.e., cells that contain comma-separated lists of values.